# I'm trying to complete the upload step to deploy a candy machine and I get the below output

Tags: solana, candy-machine

I'm trying to complete the upload step to deploy a candy machine and I am using Metaplex v2 and I am using devnet(not using minnet-beta) and "storage": "arweave" also set to devnet but still I get the below output error:

EDIT: Thank you for suggestion actually I have checked my balance it was 0 then added to SOL now it is working well!

````
Beginning the upload for 10 (img+json) pairs
started at: 1642285341323
initializing candy machine
Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit. 
    
Translating error SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3689:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3649:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:27:21)
    at async Provider.send (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:114:18)
    at async Object.rpc [as initializeCandyMachine] (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:19:23)
    at async createCandyMachineV2 (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/accounts.ts:149:11)
    at async uploadV2 (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/commands/upload.ts:134:19)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:184:7) {
  logs: []
}
Error deploying config to Solana network. SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3689:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3649:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:27:21)
    at async Provider.send (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:114:18)
    at async Object.rpc [as initializeCandyMachine] (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:19:23)
    at async createCandyMachineV2 (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/accounts.ts:149:11)
    at async uploadV2 (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/commands/upload.ts:134:19)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:184:7) {
  logs: []
}
upload was not successful, please re-run. SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3689:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:3649:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/util/send-and-confirm-raw-transaction.ts:27:21)
    at async Provider.send (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:114:18)
    at async Object.rpc [as initializeCandyMachine] (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:19:23)
    at async createCandyMachineV2 (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/helpers/accounts.ts:149:11)
    at async uploadV2 (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/commands/upload.ts:134:19)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/aziz/Desktop/nft/test/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:184:7) {
  logs: []
} ```

Please let me know if you have the other question.
Can you please help me with that and thanks to you in advance!
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you have funds in the wallet keypair you are using.

`solana balance`

Then double check your config file you are using with the -cp option.

Showing the exact cmd you are running as well would be useful.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion actually I have checked my balance it was 0 then added to SOL now it is working

Answer (score 1):

according to [metaplex candy machine v2 document](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/configuration#minimal-configuration) this is the minimum configuration:

```
{
    "price": 1.0,
    "number": 10,
    "gatekeeper": null,
    "solTreasuryAccount": "<YOUR WALLET ADDRESS>",
    "splTokenAccount": null,
    "splToken": null,
    "goLiveDate": "25 Dec 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
    "endSettings": null,
    "whitelistMintSettings": null,
    "hiddenSettings": null,
    "storage": "arweave-sol",
    "ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
    "ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
    "awsS3Bucket": null,
    "noRetainAuthority": false,
    "noMutable": false
}
```

so, you should put your devnet account public key instead of solTreasuryAccount

for creating this wallet

```
solana-keygen new --outfile ~/.config/solana/devnet.json
```

from the above command, you have the public key of generated wallet. let's call it devnet-wallet-pubkey, so for airdrop some sol to it(repeat this command once again to have enough sol):

```
solana airdrop 2 devnet-wallet-pubkey
```

now you can put this wallet public key instead of that solTreasuryAccount.